# Why is showing that ILP in NP not trivial

Tags: computational-complexity, integer-programming, np-complete

I have a question regarding the topic of showing that ILP is in NP

What is the problem with Guess and Check?

Guess a solution and then check if it is optimal.
Or further:
Calculate a solution via Simplex and then check if it is optimal.
Why is that not sufficient for showing ILP in NP?

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is with the "check it is optimal" part. How do you encode a proof of optimality? Anyway, the class NP is mostly about problems with 0/1 answer, so you should probably make it more precise how you define the ILP problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NP refers to decision problems rather than optimization problems.  A version of ILP that is in NP is

Given integer matrix $A \in \mathbb Z^{m \times n}$ and vector $b \in \mathbb Z^m$ 
does there exist a vector $x \in \mathbb Z^n$ such that $A x \le b$?

It is in NP because we can verify a "yes" answer in polynomial time: guess such an $x$ and verify that $Ax \le b$.

On the other hand, there does not seem to be any way to 
verify a "no" answer in polynomial time, i.e. this version of  ILP is not believed to be in co-NP.  Thus the following version of ILP is not believed to be in NP:

Given integer matrix $A \in \mathbb Z^{m \times n}$, vector $b \in \mathbb Z^m$, vector $c \in \mathbb Z^n$ and integer $d$, is it true that $\max \{c^T x: x \in \mathbb Z^n,  A x \le b\} = d$?